# How to make preparedstatement for 1000 different queries which will be shared across threads?

Tags: spring, performance, jdbc, prepared-statement, jdbctemplate

Currently, we have around 1000 queries which are executed(as needed i.e., all 1000 are not executed at the same time but some specific 20 are executed at high rates) as a part of a routine by the spawned taskexecutors, going through some blogs I have come to appreciate the use PreparedStatement, but currently we don't use the same. Would it be viable to switch to prepared statements while using dbcp2 as connection pool?

Comment: You shouldn't share prepared statements (nor connections) over multiple threads (at least: not concurrently). Find a connection pool that provides statement pooling and just use that: don't make it more complicated than necessary, you will more likely shoot yourself in the foot than that you will obtain a sufficiently large increase in performance.

Comment: dbcp2 says it supports statement caching. between it and spring-jdbc there shouldn't be anything extra for you to do.

Comment: so if I set the usepreparedstatement cache under dbcp2 and use jdbctemplate with prepared statement, I should be good to go?

Answer (score 1):

> *I have come to appreciate the use PreparedStatement, but currently we don't use the same.*

The typical usage is (1) prepare a statement, then (2) use it one or more times within a *single thread*. It can be faster than a regular statement even if you use it only once. So definitely try it out.

`PreparedStatement` however is not meant to be cached because it's at a level of abstraction that is too high to provide the best possible performance for all situations. The database driver is much better positioned to optimize performance in a way that is most optimal for a particular database engine.

If you care about JDBC performance, I recommend choosing [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP-benchmark) connection pool, which is specifically designed for high performance. There is also a good [explanation](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/488#issuecomment-154285114) of why HikariCP approaches statement caching differently:

> Drivers have explicit knowledge of how a given database handles
>   preparation and execution plans, and can implement caching much more
>   efficiently. Both in terms of memory footprint and execution speed.
>
> Consider that at the pool level, the pool has no choice but to cache
>   JDBC PreparedStatement objects on a per connection basis. If a user
>   says they want to cache 250 prepared statements, and the pool has 50
>   connections, that's 12500 objects. Or 50000 objects, with 500
>   statements and 100 connections. And that is not even counting things
>   like HashMap entries.
>
> Now, take PostgreSQL, as an counter example. PostgreSQL implements
>   prepared statements with something called "named queries". When you
>   prepare a statement, it is given a name. The named queries are held on
>   the server-side, along with the associated execution plan. Named
>   queries are global, and are shared across connections. The driver
>   keeps a map of SQL strings to query names.
>
> So, when you call `Connection.prepareStatement()`, the driver looks to
>   see if there is a named query for the given SQL. If so, it creates a
>   new `PreparedStatement` object that references the query by name on the
>   server-side.
>
> No `PreparedStatement` objects are kept in memory or cached. And it
>   works even if the original Connection that was used to prepare the
>   statement was closed, or the prepare was done on another Connection.
>
> This is a level of efficiency and performance that a pool cannot
>   match.
>
> I would argue that offering a statement cache would more likely hurt
>   the users of other databases, rather than help. I can say that with
>   some confidence, because a large number of users switching from BoneCP
>   or DBCP to HikariCP have asked "Where's the statement cache?!" Without
>   even knowing that it was supported inherently by their driver. Better.

For example, when using MySQL, PreparedStatement caching can be enabled in the driver itself like this:

```
HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname");
config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
```

Comment: since I will be using a connection pool, so if I create a preparedstatement at any point of time after configuring the datasource with the above properties mentioned,the cache will begin to be handled,what I am doubtful about is if while using JdbcTemplate.execute() is Connection.prepareStatement() called internally? If it doesn't then is there any specific syntax which calls Connection.prepareStatement() internally for JdbcTemplate?

Comment: `JdbcTemplate` as the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D,%20org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper%29) states always uses `prepareStatement()`: *Query given SQL to create a **prepared statement** from SQL...*. So you only need to enable statement caching in the driver.